# How can i Access "ThisWorkbook " of excel in c#

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Below Is Created Module1.bas and Storing the code on it. i would like to add the below code to 
trigger the macro From "Thisworkbook".

How can i add Workbook_Open() in Thisworkbook ?

> sCode ="Private Sub Workbook_Open()\r\n" +
>                     "UserForm1.Show\r\n" +
>                     "end sub"

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using VBIDE = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
VBIDE.VBComponent oModule;
String sCode;
oModule = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
sCode ="Private Sub Workbook_Open()\r\n" +
                  "UserForm1.Show\r\n" +
                  "end sub"
oModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var workbookMainModule = wkBk.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("ThisWorkbook");
    workbookMainModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode);
```